# Use object passed into function without changing the object

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I pass object passed into function without changing even if the passed object is has changed.

```
let theObj = {
    parameter: '11'
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function myFunc(myObj) {
    await sleep(5000)
    console.log(myObj.parameter)
}

myFunc(theObj)
theObj.parameter = '22'
```

output:

```
> 22
```

How can I get 11 as the output, the value of `theObj.parameter` when the function was called ?

I don't want to deep clone because of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator

```js
let theObj = {
    parameter: '11'
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function myFunc(myObj) {
    await sleep(5000)
    console.log(myObj.parameter)
}

myFunc({...theObj})
theObj.parameter = '22'
```

Comment: OP said : 'I don't want to deep clone because of speed.'

Answer (score 0):

Objects are [passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference), so you need to pass a *copy* of the object to your *myFunc* function.

There are [multiple approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) to copying an object, but for your case this would work:

```
myFunc({...theObj})
theObj.parameter = '22'
```

Comment: OP said : 'I don't want to deep clone because of speed.'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying, you can save the value before the await.

```js
let theObj = {
    parameter: {example: '12'},
    parameter2: 2
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function myFunc(myObj) {
    let parameter = myObj.parameter
    let parameter2 = myObj.parameter2
    
    await sleep(5000)
    console.log(parameter, parameter2)
}

myFunc(theObj)
theObj.parameter = '22'
```

Comment: This will fail if myObj.parameter is an object

Comment: @user3437245, Check example